# How to merge ActiveRecord::Relation objects and add only the value, not the key

Tags: ruby

I have a simple question about programming in Ruby. I'm a newbie to Ruby, so if somebody can help me, I will really appreciate it.

Assume a system lets users have buyer and seller feedback ratings. I want to add/merge the buy and sell feedback ratings for a user into one consolidated rating, so only the rating needs to be added from the two Relation objects. The user id is only used as the key, but is not added.

```
 buy_rating = user_object.group(buy_feedback_rating).select('buy_feedback_rating, COUNT(id) as count')
 sell_rating = user_object.group(sell_feedback_rating).select('sell_feedback_rating, COUNT(id) as count')
```

`buy_rating` and `sell_rating` are histograms of the user's buy/sell rating, with 1=Terrible, 2=Poor, 3=Average, 4=Good, 5=Very Good.

The following is a sample array with (key,value) pairs where *key=rating* from 1 to 5, and *value=number of ratings*

**buy rating = [(1,2),(2,5),(3,1),(4,7),(5,6)]**

**sell rating = [(1,3),(2,2),(3,7),(4,4),(5,7)]**

**Desired output = [(1,5),(2,7),(3,8),(4,11),(5,13)]**

(obtained by adding only the second values from each array, not the first values).

The buy_rating and sell_rating arrays will only have the the key->value pair if the value>0. Meaning, if a buyer has no buyer rating=1, then the pair (1,0) will not be present in the buy_rating array. This means the arrays could be as follows:

buy_rating = [[2,5],[3,1],[4,7]]

sell_rating = [[1,3],[2,2],[5,7]]

Question is, how do I achieve the desired result? I want to add only the second column, not the first, from each array. Object returned should be of the same data type as `buy_rating` and `sell_rating`, i.e. buy_rating and sell_rating are both ActiveRecord::Relation objects, and **the result should also be an ActiveRecord::Relation object**.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a map of values, sum based on the first, index, and then convert back to an array

```
buy_rating = [[1,2],[2,5],[3,1],[4,7],[5,6]]
sell_rating = [[1,3],[2,2],[3,7],[4,4],[5,7]]

merged_ratings = buy_rating + sell_rating

composite_ratings = Hash.new(0)

merged_ratings.each do |rating|
  composite_ratings[rating[0]]+=rating[1]
end

composite_ratings.to_a
```

Check this fiddle: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/2d0f9/2

Comment: Thanks. There is one complication I forgot to mention. The buy_rating and sell_rating arrays will only have the the key->value pair if the value>0. Meaning, if a buyer has no buyer rating=1, then the pair (1,0) will not be present in the buy_rating array. This means the arrays could be as follows: buy_rating = [[2,5],[3,1],[4,7]];
sell_rating = [[1,3],[2,2],[5,7]]

Comment: Ok, I changed my solution completely. How about this?

Comment: Make sure you update your question with this new information.

Comment: Thanks. Do I get back an ActiveRecord::Relation object?

Comment: No, the resulting object in an Array.

Comment: I need to get back an ActiveRecord::Relation object.

Comment: @roytony That's a completely different question **again**. You cannot go back to a relation after both sets of records have been converted to arrays, that makes no sense. What exactly makes you think you need this as a relation?

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying. There is a method I am calling that expects the Relation object. I suppose I will have to modify that method to accept an array. Thanks.